# Fluid Simulation not working/glitched

Tags: fluid-simulation

hopefuly one of you can help. Im trying to create a fluid sim. Im trying to create a pipe. I add a circle and set the fluid type to be the inflow and set the inflow velocity and then add the domain etc etc. But when I bake it does not look like water at all.

This happens sometimes and I have no idea why?
Here is an image https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8PSY.jpg

Comment: I can only think of checking your gravity settings in blender, or looking at other settings in the fluid sim. Could you attach the .blend?

Comment: sure thing, where should I upload it to?

Comment: If you could upload it here, that'd be great. You can edit the question and attach it.

Comment: I don't see the attach button...